# How to create a iOS static framework which refers to other static libraries/frameworks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I am working on a static framework. Now I have to add support for some other third party libraries to it.

Which is the best approach to link a static library to a iOS static framework?

Comment: I hope setting header search path will work.

Comment: I suggest to use cocoapod tool. It's very simply to implement it and manage many static libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do this with the below approach, this is without adding the dependancy static libraries into the static framework.

1. Added the dependancy libraries to the linked binaries section in the Build phase of the Static Framework to build it.
2. Used id & NSClassFromString to avoid strong reference to the classes used in the dependancy libraries
3. So when the built static framework is used in a project, the dependancies are added to the project.